# Order of registry read/remove during uninstall from a wix installer

Tags: windows, iis, wix, registry, uninstallation

I have an installer (made using wix). During installation it takes input from user to be used in setting up an IIS website. Now the problem was that during uninstall it was corrupting the IIS default website and my assumption was that this is because during uninstall it is not having that user input. 
So to solve this I am storing the user input in registry and then reading it and using it to setup the site (during installation). So during installation it creates the registry key/value, then read it and use it to create site. Assuming that during uninstall it does th reverse i.e reads it and then remove it, the problem should have been resolved. Unfortunately this is not the case.
Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding you correct, you want the IIS Website to be left over after your program is uninstalled. If that is the case you have to declare a condition so that the setting up of the website only occurs on install.

```
NOT (REMOVE ~= "ALL")
```

That should solve the problem for you.